# How to update MS Access database in C# with foreach-loop from my DataTable object with SQL command?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, datatable

I'm trying to update my MS Access database with a a foreach loop which iterates over all rows of my DataTable object which I see in my DataGrid (WPF); it should update the table in the database.

After I made some changes in a row of a column, I want to save them. But my SQL command only reacts one time (last loop). The MessageBox shows the correct row I want to update in every loop. But when I open the database again the whole column is empty.

Hope someone can help me :) I'm an absolute beginner to programming btw

```
OleDbCommand Command2 = new OleDbCommand();
Command2.Connection = Connection;

Connection.Open();

foreach (DataRow DR1 in DT1.Rows)
{
    string S1 = Convert.ToString(DR1["Column1"]);
    MessageBox.Show("Current Row: " + S1 +" will be updated");

    Command2.CommandText = "UPDATE Table1 SET Column1= '" + S1 + "' WHERE ID = 0 ";
    Command2.ExecuteNonQuery();   
}

Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.fill?view=netframework-4.8).  Then modify DataTable.  Next Add CommaNDS (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).  Now you can use the Adapter Update Method to write changes back to database.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Hmm i tried to implement it like you told me, but it still wont work. Only the last iterate of my foreach-loop is writing it back to my Database :X I used DataAdapter "DA1" this time.

Comment: Does database have a primary key.?  The ExecuteNonQerry returns an integer indicating number of rows changed.  What is the value?  Looks like code is writting back the same that is read.  How do you know that only last row is writing back?  Are you getting an exception?   How many times are you going through the for loop?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply :) The Database dont have a primary Key. I check the Database with Access and look if it updates Data. There i can see if the Data got updated. I tried some other things and now only the first loop is working.

Comment: If you see changes in Access then the view in c# is not getting updated after the changes are made.  How are you viewing the data in c#?

Comment: I can see and change my Data in a DataGrid

Comment: The DataGrid is not getting updated after you are writing to the database.  You are writing to the DataTable not the DataGrid.

Comment: AAAAAh finally i got it. Ty bro for your help :)) I post my code. forgot to use the adapter!

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me :)

```
foreach (DataRow DR1 in DT1.Rows)
               {
                  
                    DA1.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 = @Column1 WHERE ID= @ID", Connection);
                    DA1.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Column1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DR1["Column1"]);
                    DA1.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DR1["ID"]);
                    DA1.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   
                }
```